# Sinch video calling is not working on updated versions of browsers on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, sinch

I downloaded the code from [this](https://www.sinch.com/downloads/). I successfully generated the app key.

I implemented the examples code from above downloaded samples it is working fine on mobile and web. But when i tried to implement video calling i got error

`Error retrieving media stream
OverconstrainedError: Constraints could be not satisfied.`

I tried with older versions of chrome browser. it is working fine.
Don't know why its not working on updated browser.
Any idea would be appreciate.

Comment: Are you running the JS sdk on mobile? Anyway, the newer Chrome on Desktop require either that you launch them with flags, or https.
Or are you trying to run the JS on an android?

Comment: @cjensen i launched with `http`, how i can launch with flags ..?

Comment: flags are only for localfiles, chrome requires https when on  server other than localhost

Answer (score 2):

Chrome requires Https for mic and cam access since version 47